# Как скроллить дочерний элемент без скроллинга родительского?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Здравствуйте! Вроде как нашел ответ [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29889468/how-to-stop-the-scrolling-of-parent-scroll-view-when-child-scroll-view-is-scroll), но мне непонятно, какой layout подставлять вместо parentLayouttId. Подставлял корневой LinearLayout, ScrollView, непосредственно родительский LinearLayout по отношению к моему CalendarView. ̶Н̶и̶ ̶у̶ ̶к̶о̶г̶о̶ ̶и̶х̶ ̶н̶и̶х̶ ̶н̶е̶т̶ ̶м̶е̶т̶о̶д̶а̶ ̶r̶e̶q̶u̶e̶s̶t̶D̶i̶s̶a̶l̶l̶o̶w̶I̶n̶t̶e̶r̶c̶e̶p̶t̶T̶o̶u̶c̶h̶E̶v̶e̶n̶t̶(̶)̶

Для тайм пикера сделал так (пробовал и все три элемента, как здесь, и по отдельности):

```
final LinearLayout linearLayout1 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.firstParentLinear);
final ScrollView scrollView = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.secondParentScroll);
final LinearLayout linearLayout2 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.thirdParentLinear);
timePicker.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()
{
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
    {
        linearLayout1.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
        scrollView.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
        linearLayout2.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
        return false;
    }
});
```

final попросила добавить студия, без него была ошибка. По-прежнему не работает. Проверяю на реальном устройстве с версией Андроида 4.0.4. На эмуляторе версии 4.4 такой костыль не требуется, работает и без него.

Структура моего layout'а такова:

```
<LinearLayout
    ...
    <ScrollView
        ...

        <LinearLayout
            ...

            <CalendarView

            </CalendarView>

            <TimePicker

            </TimePicker>

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

В 5-6 Андроиде календарь и часы имеют удобный вид, где ничего скролить не надо, но под 4 андроид и календарь и часы нужно скролить вверх-вниз, для того, чтобы выставить нужную дату/время.
Когда я пытаюсь прокручивать календарь на другой месяц, он слегка дергается, но прокручивается весь layout, т.к. он находится в ScrollView.

Как во время прокрутки дочернего элемента не прокручивать родительский?
Как в calendarView сделать горизонтальную прокрутку? (в 4 андроиде; в 5-6 она и так есть)

Comment: как это у них нет такого метода? Всё есть, получше посмотрите

Comment: @АндроидАндроид, обновил вопрос

Answer (score 3, accepted):

как вариант вам пикеры повесить на какие-нибудь кнопки, чтобы по клику они открывались. Можно даже заюзать кастомные с [github](https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker)-a, дабы на всех версиях они смотрелось одинаково. В любом случае иметь скролящегося потомка и родителя - не тру.

Comment: Они и так у меня на чекбоксах висят, но меняется лишь параметр видимости (GONE, VISIBLE), а я так понял, вы имеете в виду, что по нажатию на кнопку мое активити переходит в состояние onPause() и поверх открывается, новое активити с календарем внутри? Хм, думаю, это выход. А за ссылку на гитхаб спасибо, очень симпатичный пикер, но хочется использовать стандартный.

Comment: Вам не надо открывать новое активити, в примере который я вам скинул, он вызывается с помощью метода show()